# This row belongs to another table error in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have 2 DataGridView namely `dgvEmpEnrollees` and `dgvEmpMustAttend` which have a DataTable as data sources namely `dtEnrollees` and `dtMustAttend` respectively.

I have a `btnRemove` which removes the currently selected row in the `dgvEmpEnrollees` datagridview `dtEnrollees` DataTable and immediately updates the  Datagridview  and I want this same row to be added in the second DT and DGV.

Note: The 2 DataTables are cloned:

`btnRemove` code snippet is as follows:

```
    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRowView currentDataRowView = (DataRowView)dgvEmpEnrollees.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
            DataRow row = currentDataRowView.Row;

            dtEnrollees.Rows.Remove(row);
            dgvEmpEnrollees.DataSource = null;
            dgvEmpEnrollees.DataSource = dtEnrollees;


            dtMustAttend.Rows.InsertAt(row,0);
            dgvEmpMustAttend.DataSource = null;
            dgvEmpMustAttend.Rows.Clear();
            dgvEmpMustAttend.DataSource = dtMustAttend;

        }
```

This row belongs to another table error in C# prompts afterwards.

I have also tried the `dtMustAttend.ImportRow(row);` method, it doesn't prompt an error but the row won't add.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried cloning the row?

Answer (score 1):

The row is really deleted from the `DataTable` with this line:

```
dtEnrollees.Rows.Remove(row);
```

Also any data is removed from the row. If you check the `ItemArray`-property after `Remove()`, it will state:

`'test.ItemArray' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.RowNotInTableException'`

Another problem is that the row still has the `Table`-property set to the table where it was. At first you used the `InsertAt()`-method, but it fails because the `Table`-property is still set to other table.

When you used the `ImportRow()`, the row had already cleared it's `ItemArray`, so you were trying to add an empty row.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution but I don't know what seems to be the explanation behind it.

I tried interchanging the import and remove codes (import comes first) and it worked.

The working code snippet:

```
 private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRowView currentDataRowView = (DataRowView)dgvEmpEnrollees.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
            DataRow row = currentDataRowView.Row;

            dtMustAttend.ImportRow(row);
            dgvEmpMustAttend.DataSource = null;
            dgvEmpMustAttend.Rows.Clear();
            dgvEmpMustAttend.DataSource = dtMustAttend;

            dtEnrollees.Rows.Remove(row);
            dgvEmpEnrollees.DataSource = null;
            dgvEmpEnrollees.DataSource = dtEnrollees;

        }
```

I don't know why the code doesn't work if the remove transaction comes first:

```
 private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRowView currentDataRowView = (DataRowView)dgvEmpEnrollees.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
            DataRow row = currentDataRowView.Row;

            dtEnrollees.Rows.Remove(row);
            dgvEmpEnrollees.DataSource = null;
            dgvEmpEnrollees.DataSource = dtEnrollees;

            dtMustAttend.ImportRow(row);
            dgvEmpMustAttend.DataSource = null;
            dgvEmpMustAttend.Rows.Clear();
            dgvEmpMustAttend.DataSource = dtMustAttend;

        }
```

Any explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add this as an addendum to your post, not as an answer with even more questions.